# Elisp: Symbol's value as variable is void with let* and (lambda)

Tags: debugging, emacs, elisp, lexical-scope

Disclaimer: I started to hack around with elisp today.

I am really wondering what I am getting the following error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: response
```

with the following code:

```
(let* ((response (cons 'dict nil)))
  (nrepl-request:eval
   code 
   (lambda (resp) 
      (print resp (get-buffer "*sub-process*"))
      (nrepl--merge response resp))
   (cider-current-connection) 
   (cider-current-session)))
```

My understanding is that `response` is in the scope of the `let*` clause when called from the lambda function... but apparently that it is not.

[This also seem to be working in this code](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/blob/e97036bc283950ecc1323fd02f82684cd0537155/nrepl-client.el#L940)

So I am a bit lost about why I am getting this error and what I should do about it.

Comment: With dynamic binding, the value for `response` is bound when your lambda is *defined*, but clearly that function is not being *called* within that same scope, and so `response` has no value at that point (unless it was bound elsewhere, of course).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify lexical binding, by setting global variable `lexical-binding` as a file-local variable in your source file. Put a line like this as the first line of the file:

```
;;;  -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
```

Either do that or use `lexical-let*` instead of `let*`.

Alternatively, if you do not need variable `response` **as a variable** when the anonymous function is invoked, that is, if you need only its value at the time the function was defined, then you can use this:

```
(let* ((response (cons 'dict nil)))
  (nrepl-request:eval
   code 
   `(lambda (resp) 
      (print resp (get-buffer "*sub-process*"))
      (nrepl--merge ',response resp)) ; <===== Substitute value for variable
   (cider-current-connection) 
   (cider-current-session)))
```

With the lexical variable, the lambda form gets compiled when you byte-compile the file. Without the variable (i.e., with just its value), the lambda form is not compiled -- it is just a list (with car `lambda` etc.).